# Clone BOOTCAMP partiton for later full restore [OSX]

Tags: macos, mac, backup, boot-camp, time-machine

I have 2 Macs at home, a Macbook Pro and a Mac Mini. I want to move the Minis data to MBPs and vice versa.

I made a time machine backup of both Macs, on my external HDD.

The challenge is that both have BOOTCAMP, at different partition sizes (Mini has 100GB and MbP has 150GB).

What is the best practice to perform a full backup of Windows too?

I want to clean install OSX on both and restore my data from TimeMachine as well as get my Bootcamps back (TimeMachine only backs up the OSX partition)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/winclone/) for my Windows BOOTCAMP partition and TimeMachine for OSX.
Booted up recovery partition and restored from TimeMachine, then restored BOOTCAMP partition too.